# Updating a column with multiple values from another table which are linked by a group id in another column

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with two columns as below in which res_codes are linked by group_id as below:

```
res_code Group_id
S055415    2
S055416    2
S055417    2
S055418    2
S044114    3
S044127    3
S068068    4
S068067    4
S068065    4
```

There is another table with 'res_code' as a foreign key and a 'Notes' column, I need to update (t-SQL) the notes column with all the res_codes that are linked by Group_id matching on Res_code from above table.

the other table has res_code, Notes columns along with other many columns. So I would like to update the Notes columns with values from the above table matching on a specific Res_code. So for example, Res_code S068068 will have corresponding Notes column updated with 'S068067 and S068065', as they are linked by the grp_id value of 4 in the above table.

Please advise.......

Comment: please show sample data from all related tables and the expected result

Comment: the other table has res_code, Notes columns along with other many columns. So I would like to update the Notes columns with values from the above table matching on a specific Res_code. So for example, Res_code S068068 will have corresponding Notes column updated with 'S068067 and S068065', as they are linked by the grp_id value of 4 in the above table.

Comment: please update your question with the additional information and not in comment.